# For a std::hash<CustomType> that just wraps a library-provided std::hash<T>, what is considered the best implementation?

Tags: stl, containers, c++17

I have a std::chrono::nanoseconds object I want to use as the key into an std::unordered_map, and there is no default hash for duration objects.  I am fine just wrapping .count() though.

For these very simple implementations of std::hash<...> that are just wrappers of library provided hash algorithms, what is considered the best approach?  Having the provided hasher as a class member, a local variable, or something else completely?

Example code of member vs. local implementations provided below for reference.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;

constexpr int64_t keyExtractor(const TimePoint& t) {
    return t.time_since_epoch().count();
}

struct TimePointHasherLocal
{
    std::size_t operator()(TimePoint const& s) const noexcept
    {
        return std::hash<int64_t>()(keyExtractor(s));
    }
};

struct TimePointHasherMember
{
    std::size_t operator()(TimePoint const& s) const noexcept
    {
        return hasher(keyExtractor(s));
    }
    std::hash<int64_t> hasher;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unordered_map<TimePoint, int, TimePointHasherLocal> container1;
    std::unordered_map<TimePoint, int, TimePointHasherMember> container2;
    return 0;
}
```

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/caz39bGqb)